# Android Parcelable - How to pass array of custom objects inside another array of custom objects

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, kotlin, parcelable

Let's say I have an `orders` array. Now, suppose inside each order I have a `sellers` array.

By making the `Order` class parcelable, it is not working the array of `Seller`s out.

I tried doing this:

```
class Order() : Parcelable {  

   [...]  

    constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this() {
       id = parcel.readString()
       name = parcel.readString()
       sellers = parcel.readparcel(Seller::class.java) // (I added this line)
    }

    override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
        parcel.writeString(id)
        parcel.writeString(name)
        parcel.writeparcelabl(sellers, flags) // (I added this line)
    }
}
```

But it didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use `@Parcelize`?

Comment: It didn't work :/

Comment: I don't know enough about **all** of your related classes to tell you why.

Comment: How is the variable `sellers` defined?